# Replicated MongoDB server slower than simple shards

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding

I tried to compare the performance of a sharded configuration against a sharded **and** replicated configuration.

The sharded configuration consists of 8 shards each running on three different machines thereby constituting a total of 24 shards. All 8 of these shards run in the same partition on each machine.

The sharded and replicated version is 8 shards again just like plain sharding, and all 8 `mongod`s run on the same partition in each machine. But apart from this, each of these three machine now run additional 16 threads on another partition which serve as the secondary for the 8 `mongod`s running on other machines. This is the way I prepared a sharded and replicated configuration with data chunks having replication factor of 3.

Important point to note is that once the data has been loaded, it is not modified. So after primary and secondaries have synchronized then it doesn't matter which one i read from.

To run the queries, I use an entirely different machine (let's call it config) which runs `mongos` and this machine's only purpose is to receive queries and run them on the cluster.

Contrary to my expectations, plain sharding of 8 threads on each machine (total = 3 * 8 = 24) is performing better for queries than the sharded + replicated configuration.

I have a script written to perform the query. So in order to time the scripts, I use `time ./testScript` and see the result. I tried changing the reading preference for replicated cluster by logging to mongo of config and run `db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary')` and then exit the shell and run the queries like `time ./testScript`.

The questions are:

1. Where am i going wrong in the replication? Why is it slower than its plain sharding version?
2. Does the `db.getMongo().ReadPref('secondary')` persist when i leave the shell and try to perform the query?

All the four machines are running Linux and i have already increased the ulimit -n to 2048 from initial value of 1024 to allow more connections. The collections are properly distributed and all the `mongod`s have equal number of chunks. Goes without saying that indices in both configurations are the same.

**Hardware Specifications**
 - Architecture : AMD64
 - RAM: 64 GB
 - No. of cores : 32

Comment: What are these machines and how are they networked?

Comment: Well, that's uselessly vague. There are many, many Dell servers of massively different specifications, and many different speeds of Ethernet as well. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Kindly pardon my naivety, may i know how would the make and ethernet affect when both the configurations are being deployed on the same hardware?

Comment: Who knows? You still haven't described the setup, so it's impossible to say.

Comment: Am I correct in that your non-replicated setup has 8 mongod processes on one server while your replicated setup has 24? If so you have additional processes competing for CPU and RAM.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : All the four machines have 32 AMD64 cores. They are connected via 10 Gbs private network. What more information would be needed? I think the problem is with the configuration of MongoDB for a sharded replicated design.

Comment: @JamesWahlin : You are correct. But the original 8 mongod processes are running on a separate partition altogether. And all the total 24 mongods are competing for 32 cores of the machine. All the four machines have 64GB RAM while the entire database is <20 GB. The resources are plentiful.